# Is there any relationship between the verb 死{し}ぬ and the 音読み 死{し}?

Tags: etymology, readings, history

I noticed that both 死ぬ and the 音読み of 死 share a し sound. Is this a huge coincidence between Japanese and Chinese, or is there some sort of relation? I guess the former, because I don't know any function ぬ may have after a borrowed noun, but I don't know much about etymology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a tempting identification, but the 〜ぬ suffix is inexplicable. In fact, there are only two n-stem verbs in Old Japanese – 死ぬ and 去【い】ぬ – plus one auxiliary (the perfective 〜ぬ), all of which are conjecturally related. [Linguistic coincidences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate) are not unheard of: one well-known example concerns the word "dog" in English and in Mbabaram.

For what it's worth, the 日本語国語大辞典 records the following etymological theories:

> 【語源説】
>
> (1)息がなくなる意のシイヌ（息去）の義〔日本語原学＝林甕臣〕。シイヌル（息逝）の義〔松屋棟梁集〕。
>
> (2)サリヌルの反〔名語記〕。
>
> (3)スギイヌル（過往）の義〔名言通〕。
>
> (4)シヲルル、シボム、シヒルの義と通じる〔国語の語根とその分類＝大島正健〕。
>
> (5)シは〆領る、ヌは歇了る義〔国語本義〕。

By contrast, it is generally accepted that words like 馬【うま】 and 梅【うめ】 are ancient loanwords from Chinese.

Comment: There's also a theory of 死に去ぬ>死ぬ.

Comment: Re: 馬{うま}, while likely arriving in Japanese via Chinese, that word probably originated in some central Asian language, given the proliferation of related terms throughout many otherwise-unrelated languages.  See also [馬#Japanese on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A6%AC#Japanese) and [*mark* (Proto-Indo-European) on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/mar%E1%B8%B1-).

Comment: Re: Japanese and Chinese 死, I also recall somewhere running into the theory that this might well have been some such linguistic accident, where a native proto-Japanese word for "death" just happened to sound like the Chinese word, hence the し overlap in both *on'yomi* and *kun'yomi*.  (That said, at the moment I can't remember which resource I found that in.)